# Should a javascript class explicitly return something?

Tags: javascript, oop, adobe-illustrator

I've been writing some Adobe Illustrator javascripts to improve my workflow. I've been really getting to grips with OOP recently so I've been writing it using objects and I really think it helps keep my code clean and easily up-datable. However I wanted to check some best practice with you guys.

I have a rectangle object which creates (three guesses)... a rectangle. It looks like this

```
function rectangle(parent, coords, name, guide) {

    this.top = coords[0];
    this.left = coords[1];
    this.width = coords[2];
    this.height = coords[3];
    this.parent = (parent) ? parent : doc;  

    var rect = this.parent.pathItems.rectangle(this.top, this.left, this.width, this.height);
    rect.name = (name) ? name : "Path";
    rect.guides = (guide) ? true : false;
    return rect;
}
```

However the code works fine with OR without that last

```
return rect
```

So my question is what does

```
new rectangle(args);
```

return if I don't explicitly say so?

If I do this:

```
var myRectangle = new rectangle(args);
myRectangle.left = -100;
```

It works just fine wether I `return rect` or not.

Many thanks for you help.

Comment: you can upvote my answer by clicking the up arrow. You should accept answers to your question by clicking the hollow checkmark next to my answer.

Comment: I tried upvoting it but I don't have enough reputation I'm afraid. Can you accept more than one answer? My understanding was you wait for a while and accept the best one? Yours was a great answer but I don't yet know what other people will say. Or am I not getting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript object should only have properties and methods.

Use the return keyword inside a method.

```
function rectangle(parent, coords, name, guide) {

    this.top = coords[0];
    this.left = coords[1];
    this.width = coords[2];
    this.height = coords[3];
    this.parent = (parent) ? parent : doc;  

    this.draw = function () { // add a method to perform an action.
        var rect = this.parent.pathItems.rectangle(this.top, this.left, this.width, this.height);
        rect.name = (name) ? name : "Path";
        rect.guides = (guide) ? true : false;
        return rect;
    };
}
```

How you would use your object.

```
var myRectangle = new rectangle(args);
    myRectangle.draw();
```

Comment: I've been developing a pong game in javascript and this method is what I'm using there. I don't know why I'm not doing the same thing in my Illustrator script. One reason I suppose, is it's less verbose without the draw method. Does it matter do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely unnecessary. An instance will be created and assigned automatically when you call `new`. No need to return `this` or anything like that.

In strictly OOP languages like **Java** or **C++**, constructors **do not return anything**.

Comment: Great, thanks! I didn't know that strict OOP constructors didn't return anything.

Comment: The methods inside the constructor may return 'this' for help in cascading function calls.